# Moving NSNotificationCenter Design Pattern to C++ for porting?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, observer-pattern, nsnotificationcenter

I was about to begin porting a relatively large game from iPhone Obj-C to a platform neutral C++. In our game, we made heavy use of the `NSNotificationCenter` for notifying menus and game items of downloads and cache updates from our server.

I was thinking of re-creating the `NSNotificationCenter` using a singleton class and then having any class which would receive notifications inherit a `NotificationReceiver` base class using multi-inheritance. The singleton would keep a `Map` of notification names that would keep an array of pointers to the base class. When the notification is sent, it would then call a virtual member in the base class of the receivers which could be overridden.

Is there a better design pattern to use in C++ for this type of operation?

Would there be a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would there be a better way to implement this?

Yes - there is no need to enforce inheriting a specific interface if you use e.g.:

- functors like [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/function.html) or C++11 `std::function` in combination with [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html)/`std::bind` for the callbacks
- signaling systems like [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/signals2.html).

Also keep in mind that if all you need is a single instance for the notification center, [it doesn't need to be a singleton](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/).

Comment: Why does it not need to be a singleton? The only other option I can think of is making it members and functions all static... The singleton pattern would also allow me to make other notification centers if I did not want to use the default one (as is done in Obj-C).

Comment: @David: If you need global access to a specific instance you could just as well solve that using a global or convenience access through a static method etc. - there is rarely a need to forcibly limit the class to only a single instance.

Comment: @David: Also worth noting that `NSNotificationCenter` isn't a singleton either - you can get access to different instances, it just provides convenient access to the process' default notification center.

Comment: @George Yes, I believe we are thinking the same thing. Typically in Objective-C a "singleton class" has a static accessor method which has a shared instance , even though, strictly speaking, it  is not a singleton as you can construct other instances. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @David: Right, i wasn't aware that Apple is using the term *'singleton'* more lax for things like `NSFileManager` too. Weird, but good to know.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the aforementioned `boost` packages, another option is [`poco::NotificationCenter`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/package-Foundation.Notifications.html).

This implementation is closer to the Cocoa notification framework, as specifically discussed on Poco's [documentation](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.NotificationCenter.html):

> The NotificationCenter class is basically a C++ implementation of the
>   NSNotificationCenter class found in Apple's Cocoa (or OpenStep).